2010s Netflix show where monsters took over the world
So there was an animated show on Netflix that I watched in the 2010s. In it, monsters took over the world, and the main character was trying to find survivors. None of the main characters were teens. The cast was made up of adults and one kid.
In the first episode, the main character walks into an elevator. He saw someone get tortured, but it was a kid's show, so the torture was getting tickled, I think. That's all I remember from the first episode.
In another episode, the main characters went to a library, and there were ghosts all around it. 
I also remember this scene in the show where the main character and the side characters are around a campfire near the end of an episode.
There was only mild swearing, like "damn".

Welcome to SciFi.SE! Is there anything else you can remember about this show: what year you watched it, what language it was in, whether it was live-action or animated? Any details you can provide can help us to narrow this down.

It’s was an animated show, it was English and it’s had to be 2010s. It had a little swearing like “damn”

At first, I thought it was saying that in-show, it was a kids show that they were torturing him for...

I don’t remember why he was being torturing. But another thing I’m starting to remember is this scene in the show where the main character and the side characters are around a camp fire near the end of a episode

I actually found the show I was talking about, it is called mutant busters. Including with that, the “monsters” I was talking about were actually fart mutants.. if you read the description of the show, it will explain everything lol.

@Eli You should post that as an answer and mark it as accepted to signal to others that your question has been answered.

@Eli: I wound up posting an answer so that we have one in place. You can copy any and all of my answer for your own at which point I will delete mine. In either case, you can accept an answer (including your own) by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Quickly posting a placeholder answer that the querent found the program, Mutant Busters.


After the cataclysm known as the Big Fart, Earth has turned into a giant butt under threat of mutant invasion. Sheriff is a street-smart survivor who must turn a gang of misfits and miscreants into La Résistance, a commando squad of human warriors who can fight the mutants and save the planet.

If they post, I will remove my answer. And, of course, they're welcome to borrow any of my content.
Show Intro




It's possible this was The Last Kids on Earth, which was on Netflix during 2019. It consists of three separate "books", and is a remake of a popular children's book series (the show is rated TV-Y7).
The monsters are mostly zombies, with some other ones. The MCs consisted of four teens, three guys and a girl.
I don't remember an elevator scene in the first episode, but I think there was a library similar to what you described at some point.
There was also mild swearing like "damn" (I'm pretty sure).

It's an unlikely match, but I thought I'd mention it.

No, it’s not that because none of the main characters were teens. The cast was made up of adults and one kid
